# Python core usage slower/under 100% with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Code that runs on one core @ 100% actually runs slower when multiprocessed, where it runs on several cores @ ~50%.

This question is asked frequently, and the best threads I've found about it ([0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348746/python-multiprocessing-pool-doesnt-use-100-of-each-cpu), [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727375/multiprocessing-pool-slower-than-just-using-ordinary-functions)) give the answer, "It's because the workload isn't heavy enough, so the inter-process communication (IPC) overhead ends up making things slower."

I don't know whether or not this is right, but I've isolated an example where this happens AND *doesn't* happen for *the same* workload, and I want to know whether this answer still applies or why it actually happens:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(n):
    res = 0

    for i in range(n):
        res += i**2

    return res


def single(n):
    """ Single core """
    for i in range(n):
        f(n)


def multi(n):
    """ Multi core """
    pool = Pool(2)

    for i in range(n):
        pool.apply_async(f, (n,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def single_r(n):
    """ Single core, returns """
    res = 0

    for i in range(n):
        res = f(n) % 1000 # Prevent overflow

    return res


def multi_r(n):
    """ Multi core, returns """
    pool = Pool(2)
    res = 0

    for i in range(n):
        res = pool.apply_async(f, (n,)).get() % 1000

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return res

# Run
n = 5000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"single({n})...", end='')
    single(n)
    print(" DONE")
    print(f"multi({n})...", end='')
    multi(n)
    print(" DONE")

    print(f"single_r({n})...", end='')
    single_r(n)
    print(" DONE")
    print(f"multi_r({n})...", end='')
    multi_r(n)
    print(" DONE")
```

The workload is `f()`.

`f()` is run single-cored and dual-cored **without** return calls via `single()` and `multi()`.

Then `f()` is run single-cored and dual-cored **with** return calls via `single_r()` and `multi_r()`.

My result is that slowdown happens when `f()` is run multiprocessed **with return calls**. Without returns, it doesn't happen.

So `single()` takes `q` seconds. `multi()` is much faster. Good. Then `single_r()` takes `q` seconds. But then `multi_r()` takes *much more* than `q` seconds. [Visual inspection of my system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhOK9.png) corroborates this (a little hard to tell, but the `multi(n)` hump is shaded two colors, indicating activity from two different cores).

Also, [corroborating video of the terminal outputs](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/HeavenlyAbsoluteAustraliansilkyterrier-mobile.mp4)

Even with uniform workload, is this still IPC overhead? Is such overhead only paid when other processes return their results, and, if so, is there a way to avoid it while still returning results?

Comment: I don't think this will solve your issue, but when working with multiprocessing, use the __main__ conditional to not spawn a process that executes the whole module again, I added it to your code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _I've isolated an example where this happens AND doesn't happen for the same workload_ ? What's the average runtime for the different methods? Have you used a profiler? Also, use context managers for your pools, they're great.

Comment: You are using `.get()` in your function `multi_r()` too soon.  `AsyncResult.get()` is blocking, so you don't run this parallel in your setup. What happens is you submit one job, then await the result and only then the for-loop continues submitting the next job. You need to schedule and store all "futures" you get from `.apply_async()` first and only then call `.get()` in a second loop after all jobs are already on the way.

Comment: @Darkonaut Huh, interesting! I'm a noob; could you point me to a resource for how to "store futures"?

Comment: It's just collecting them in a list like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55577761/9059420) for example.

Comment: @Darkonaut You're correct! It's a shame I can't find [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) saying .get() is blocking, but this must indeed be the case: if I first collect the apply_async() results in a list and then run .get() on them sequentially in the parent process, I see the same increase as in the `multi()` function that has no returns!

Comment: Yeah, now that you say it, the wording in the docs could surely be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Darkonaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9059420/darkonaut) pointed out, the slowdown when using multiple processes in `multi_r()` is because the `get()` call is blocking:

```
for i in range(n):
        res = pool.apply_async(f, (n,)).get() % 1000
```

This effectively runs the workload sequentially or *concurrently* (more akin to [multi*threaded*](https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-ece023ad55a)) while adding multiprocess overhead, making it run *slower* than the single-cored equivalent `single_r()`!

Meanwhile, `multi()` ran faster (i.e., ran in parallel correctly) because it contains no `get()` calls.

To run parallel *and* return results, collect result objects first as in:

```
def multi_r_collected(n):
    """ Multi core, collects apply_async() results before returning them """
    pool = Pool(2)
    res = 0

    res = [pool.apply_async(f, (n,)) for i in range(n)] # Collect first!

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    res = [r.get() % 1000 for r in res] # .get() after!

    return res
```

[Visual inspection of CPU activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uGUw.png) corroborates the noticed speed-up; when run with 12 processes via `Pool(12)`, there's a clean, uniform mesa of multiple cores clearly running at 100% in parallel (not the 50% mishmash of `multi_r(n)`).